# Entity Framework Code First Create Database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, code-first

I am new to Entity Framework.
I want to make it Database as a separate Entity In project.
So I started my project with as Class Library project.
Starting with Login so class created for it with inherit IdentityUser.

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(200)]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(500)]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

Now I want to create database , I have added key in App.Config.

```
public class AppDBContext : DbContext
{
    public AppDBContext():base("AppDBConnectionString")
    {

    }
}
```

Any Package Manager command to create database for first time ?
Update-Database didnt work.

Comment: When you say "Update-Database didn't work.", what does that mean, exactly? did you receive some sort of error?

Comment: What version of Entity Framework are you using? EF7 had some major changes to how you create the database.

Comment: @Claies Specify the '-Verbose' flag to view the SQL statements being applied to the target database.
No migrations configuration type was found in the assembly 'AspNetIdentity.Data'. (In Visual Studio you can use the Enable-Migrations command from Package Manager Console to add a migrations configuration).

Comment: so it sounds like you haven't enabled migrations yet on your project.

Comment: @JosephGarrone Right now using EF6 , if EF7 has has new feature to creating database and managing easily . I can update that too.

Comment: @Claies Before migration I would like to create database first time.

Comment: You're missing your `DbSet<ApplicationUser> ApplicationUsers { get; set; }` property...

Comment: creating the database is the initial migration.

Comment: @NovaDev Thanks Added.

Comment: @Claies Yes understand , it requires .. now bit getting used to it :) One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:

AspNetIdentity.Data.IdentityUserLogin: : EntityType 'IdentityUserLogin' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
AspNetIdentity.Data.IdentityUserRole: : EntityType 'IdentityUserRole' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.

Comment: EF can identify keys based on their name, but the name usually must have an ID in the name, (e.g. `KeyID`) for it to be recognized. So, you could use an attribute to identify your key `[Key]` in the line above your key instead.

Comment: Another question: I notice that your table inherits from IdentityUser. Does that mean that the key is defined there? If so, I'm not sure if that's a good idea.

Comment: @NovaDev Yes I inherits IdentityUser class , I want to get advantage of Aspnet.Identity.

Comment: I think you likely need to add a Key to your ApplicationUser table, as I define above. I looked at IdentityUser on MSDN, and while there is an ID, it's not the same as the table you care about having its own Key. So maybe `ApplicationUserID` should be your key...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, to summarize, update your class to include a key:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
[Key]
public int ApplicationUserId { get; set; }

[Required]
[MaxLength(200)]
public string FirstName { get; set; }
[Required]
[MaxLength(500)]
public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

And update your DbSet in your AppDbContext to:

```
DbSet<ApplicationUser> ApplicationUsers { get; set; }
```